# comparing contents of divs in jquery, why it doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="header1">
  sth
    <span>
      ::before
      sth2
    </span>
</div>

<div class="pure-menu-link">
  sth2
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var titleToHide = $('.header1 span').html();
      titleToHide = titleToHide.replace('::before', '');
      titleToHide.trim();

      var titleToCompare = $('.pure-menu-link').html();
      titleToCompare.trim();

      if (titleToHide === titleToCompare){
            $('.pure-menu-link').hide();
      };
</script>
```

I'm trying to compare contents of span inside header1 and pure-menu-link, i need to hide p-m-l element when header1 is empty. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: You need to assign the result of trim() back to something

Comment: trim() doesn't do inplace manipulation it returns the manipulated value

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to the whitespaces differences between the two `html()` values. `trim()` is the right method to use to get rid of any extraneous whitespace before comparing, but you need to update your variables with its output, like this:

```js
var titleToCompare = $('.pure-menu-link').html();
var titleToHide = $('.header1 span').html().replace('::before', '');

// note the whitespace difference in the console...
console.log(titleToHide); 
console.log(titleToCompare);

// use trim() to fix this
titleToHide = titleToHide.trim();
titleToCompare = titleToCompare.trim();

if (titleToHide === titleToCompare) {
    $('.pure-menu-link').hide();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header1">
  sth
    <span>
      ::before
      sth2
    </span>
</div>

<div class="pure-menu-link">
  sth2
</div>
```